# How to get web table value in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I  am facing some issues for getting the column value from a web table in selenium webdriver. Please let me know how to get the value.

`HTML`:

```
<table id="ext-gen1916" class="x-grid-table x-grid-table-resizer x-unselectable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 4569px; -moz-user-select: none;"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused x-grid-row-over">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1157 x-grid-clean-cell x-grid-cell-special x-grid-cell-first">
    <td id="ext-gen1949" class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-actioncolumntext-1115 x-grid-clean-cell x-action-col-cell ">
    <td id="ext-gen1943" class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1126 x-grid-clean-cell ">
    <td id="ext-gen1944" class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1127 x-grid-clean-cell ">
    <td id="ext-gen1917" class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1128 x-grid-clean-cell ">
        <div id="ext-gen1918" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: left;" unselectable="on">FP</div>
    </td>
```

`Java` code:

```
ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[15]/div")); 
ele.getText(); 
System.out.println(ele.getText());
```

Comment: Little more source code will be helpful to understand the problem. And show us what you have tried.

Comment: What issues? Share your code along with issue description, exception log

Comment: @Andersson I tried this one, ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[15]/div"));
       ele.getText();
       System.out.println(ele.getText());

Answer (score 1):

Try to use more specific selector:

```
ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div[starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen') and @class='x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable']"));
```

Also check whether `table` located inside an `iframe`. In such case you need to switch to `iframe` before "searching" for element:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Frame_ID");
```

Comment: @ Andersson , for all td's id name starts with 'ext-gen' and class is also same

Comment: and each `td` has child `div`? Do you get wrong value or you don't get any or exception raised?

Comment: Yes each td has child div

Comment: Is it possible to share page `URL`? Does `"(//td/div[starts-with(@id, 'ext-gen') and @class='x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable'])[5]"` works?